# Pairing Request - not exported from uid 1000

Tags: android, bluetooth, uid

I try to open a pairing dialog to a specific MAC address.

```
BluetoothDevice device;
String bt_mac = read.toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN);
device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(bt_mac);
Intent intent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");
intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE", device);
intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT", 0);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But all I receive is this error message:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothPairingDialog (has
>   extras) } from ProcessRecord{434110a0 15553:de.test.testapp/u0a10003}
>   (pid=15553, uid=10003) not exported from uid 1000

I think the problem is this part of the message: not exported from uid 1000
But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Do you have the permission `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` set?

Comment: Yes I have.                                                        <uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Answer (score 0):

According to [AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), the PAIRING REQUEST belongs to "special broadcasts that only the system can send":

```
    <protected-broadcast android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST" />
```

I guess that other users proposing this as a solution (e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138163/pairing-request-not-exported-from-uid-1000) question) might have root rights.